# PyQgis Raster Style Editor Dialog

Tags: pyqgis, rendering

I know that for `QgsVectorLayer`, there is the `QgsSymbolV2SelectorDialog` dialog that I can call to allow users to change vector layer's styles. I am looking for an equivalent dialog for `QgsRasterLayer`. I found a `QgsRasterRendererWidget` and I put it in a `QDialog`, but when I instantiate it like:

`layer = QgsRasterLayer()
editor = QgsRasterRendererWidget(layer, layer.extent())`

it gave the following exception:

`TypeError: qgis._gui.QgsRasterRendererWidget represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated`

So, is there a dialog class that I can use to open the raster property dialog to allow users to change raster render style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For raster layer, use `QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRendererWidget` and `QgsMultiBandColorRendererWidget`